# How to get both value and label of SelectControl?

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to get both the value and label in a SelectControl.

If I do:

```
<SelectControl
    label={ __( 'Content Type' ) }
    value={ contenttype }
    options={ contenttypeControlOptions }
    onChange={ ( selectedContentTypeOption ) => {
        props.setAttributes( {
            contenttype: selectedContentTypeOption,
            contentlabel: ?,
        } );
    } }
/>
```

I get the value just fine. But how to set the label as well? I thought the variable `selectedContentTypeOption` would be an object for the selected item but it is just a string for the option value. I am new to React so perhaps there is something obvious I am overlooking!

Comment: is SelectControl your component or third party?

Comment: Try to get the actual onChange event, there you can get the label from.

Comment: I ended up just using a filter var name = contenttypeControlOptions.filter(obj => {
                return obj.value === selectedContentTypeOption
            }); probably not very elegant way but working